# How can I output a string plus wild card in linux from a file?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, grep

So I have a log/text file. in that file there is a bunch of information, but I'm looking to only get a certain string.

```
@@204,clientDisconnect,"apMac"="60:d0:2c:3a:f2:60","clientMac"="8c:45:00:84:e8:98","ssid"="Th","userId"="","wlanId"="240","iface"="wlan32","tenantU,19",,"userName"="d","vlanId"="512","radio"="a/n/ac","encryption"="WPA2-AES","osType"="Android","hostname"="Galaxy-S9","firstAuth"="1580412687","associationTime"="1580411444","ipAssignTime"="1580412688","disconnectTime"="1580412724","sessionDuration"="37","disconnectReason"="8","rxFrames"="26","rxBytes"="4415","txFrames"="93","txBytes"="22693","peakRx"="4415","peakTx"="22693","rssi"="62","receivedSignalStrength"="-43","Instantaneous
```

I only want the `disconnectReason = "8"` . but that disconnect number can change depending how why the client disconnected. I'm not sure how to search the file and only output that string with a wild card.

I'd like it to output:

```
disconnectReason ="8"
disconnectReason ="3"
disconnectReason ="1" etc.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways the go about this, based on what you said this should be sufficient for your needs:

```
grep -oE '"disconnectReason"="[0-9]+"' yourfile
```

`-o` tells `grep` to return only the matching part of the string

Comment: Slight bug: you need double quotes around `disconnectReason` to match, but this is indeed much better than using sed as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the example you give is a single line in the file, you can use `sed` to delete everything before and everything after the field you are after:

```
sed -E 's/.*,("disconnectReason"="[0-9]+"),.*/\1/' <file>
```

This "remembers" the field and value you are interested in by using a parenthesized sub-expression, and then uses `\1` to refer to the first (and only in this case) remembered sub-expression to replace the while line by.

If you are really adamant about deleting the double quotes around `disconnectReason`, I would do that with another sed filter, instead of complicating the regexp. It is perhaps less efficient, but it is much easier to read:

```
sed -E 's/.*,("disconnectReason"="[0-9]+"),.*/\1/' <file> |
   sed -E 's/"(disconnectReason)"/\1/'
```

Comment: in one go you can do `sed -E 's/.*"(disconnectReason)\s*"=(\s*"[0-9]+").*/\1 =\2/' infile`